# Using YouTube API to retrieve information of past searches

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I wonder if there is any way to get a list of the searches done with the same key using YouTube API. I could not find it on the API documentation.

I have several computers running a searching code, using YouTube API.

The keyword used is picked randomly from a list of terms. All computers use the same key.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,
Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API won't do that, but you can save the searches on your end.